# Petición HTTP GET ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema de Spring RestTemplate (getForEntity) + JSON en Java?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

> Quiero recuperar la información mediante una librería a la API de Codewars con mi User en formato JSON. La petición (GET,la cual te devuelve un JSON con la información de tu user) es esta [https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/(aquí](https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/(aqu%C3%AD) va el nombre del usuario).
>   Lo primero que hice fue obtener el JSON (añadiendo el nombre de mi usuario) y utilicé un JSON to Java para obtener el código Java correspondiente. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
>   Aquí el JSON:

```
{
    username: "minombredeusuario",
    name: null,
    honor: 2,
    clan: "pepito",
    leaderboardPosition: 500793,
    skills: null,
    ranks: {
        overall: {
            rank: -8,
            name: "8 kyu",
            color: "white",
            score: 2
        },
        languages: {
            java: {
                rank: -8,
                name: "8 kyu",
                color: "white",
                score: 2
            }
        }
    },
    codeChallenges: {
        totalAuthored: 0,
        totalCompleted: 1
    }
}
```

> Y aquí mi método:

```
 public User getUser() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    User user = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/(aqui mi nombre de usuario)", User.class).getBody();
    return  ;
}
```

> El problema que me surge es que el JSON to Java me ha generado 6 clases diferentes, aquí una de ellas:

```
package entities;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)

@JsonPropertyOrder({
"overall",
"languages"
})

public class Ranks {

@JsonProperty("overall")
private Overall overall;

@JsonProperty("languages")
private Languages languages;

@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 


@JsonProperty("overall")
public Overall getOverall() {
return overall;
}

@JsonProperty("overall")
public void setOverall(Overall overall) {
this.overall = overall;
}

@JsonProperty("languages")
public Languages getLanguages() {
return languages;
}

@JsonProperty("languages")
public void setLanguages(Languages languages) {
this.languages = languages;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

> Me genera otras 5 clases (Java,Overall,Mail,Languages,CodeChallenges) con el mismo formato(getters,setters..) Entonces el método public UsergetUser que os he mostrado estaría mal, no sé qué devolver(o si hacer el método void) ni qué clase utilizar en el método, puesto que quiero recuperar toda la información no solo una porción.
>   Anotación: User es un JavaBean cuyos atributos son Integer id y String username.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que la clase Mail debería ser renombrada a User, puesto que no hay ningún atributo `"mail"` en esa estructura. Por cierto, lo que has puesto no es JSON válido, faltan las comillas dobles para las claves.

Comment: Justamente era eso. Suponer la clase Mail como la principal y acotarlo a mi proyecto. Muchas gracias por los dos apuntes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ para generar las clases, esta aplicación online usa el JSON que le ofreces como referencia. Por ejemplo:

```
{
  "cosas": { ...},
  "nombre": "Pablo"
}
```

Asume que lo guardado en el atributo `"cosas"` es un objeto que tendrá ciertos atributos y crea una clase llamada `Cosas` con esos atributos, que recursivamente podrán crear a su vez más clases *ad hoc*. También asume que `"nombre"` es un String, pero lo que no puede adivinar es el nombre de la clase que tiene `"cosas"` y `"nombre"` como atributos, porque es el objeto raíz y no tiene identificador.

Viendo el código que has puesto, está claro que el nombre que le has puesto es Mail cuando debería ser User. Renombrando la clase deberías solucionar el problema.

Comment: Correcto si,era eso muchas gracias

Comment: @Tucan12 Me alegro de haberte ayudado. Te recomiendo leerte el [tour] de bienvenida para entender cómo funciona el sitio. Por otro lado, estaría genial si marcases la respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta quede *respondida*